# MYSQL AVG Score Of First Attempt Of 3 Different Tests - IN GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have 2 tables

```
Users: id, name
Results: id, test_id, user_id, score
```

I need to get the average of the user's first attempt over all three test_id's.

The user may not have completed all 3 tests.

The query I have here does work but is extremely slow, is there a way of speeding this up?

```
SELECT AVG(score) 
  FROM results 
 WHERE id IN(SELECT MIN(id) 
               FROM results 
               WHERE complete = 1 
               GROUP 
                  BY test_id)
```

Comment: Just to clarify, can a user have multiple scores for a given test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses a subquery to get the minimum id for each user/test combination.  It then joins back to `results` to get the `score` and uses that for the aggregation:

```
SELECT u.*, AVG(r.score)
FROM user u LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT user, testid, MIN(id) as minid
      FROM results r
      WHERE complete = 1
      GROUP BY user_id, test_id
     ) ut
     ON ut.user_id = u.id LEFT JOIN
     results r
     ON r.id = ut.minid
GROUP BY u.id;
```

This produces the average for each user (which is how I interpret the question).  If you want the average over all users of the first of each test, then remove the `group by` and `user` table from the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a subquery and `JOIN` it instead of the correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  r1.id,
  r2.test_id,
  r2.avgstore
FROM results AS r1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT test_id, MIN(id) AS MinId, AVG(Store) AS AvgStore
   FROM results 
   WHERE complete = 1 
   GROUP BY test_id
) AS r2 ON r1.id = r2.MinId AND r1.test_id = r2.test_id;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c924/6)

Comment: Thanks @Mahmood, this is great. How would I get an accurate AVG of all three? Could I just take AVG(r2.avgstore) ?

Comment: @TommyArnold - Do you mean all the tests? completed or not?

Comment: Currently, the above query returns 3 rows, I am looking for one row with the average of all three.

Comment: Yes, you can add `AVG(avgstore)`, but it won't give you the right results as you already gouped by `test_id` in the subquery and the id is the min id, you should decide for which group the `AVG` should be calculated, for each user or for each test??

Comment: The ideal result would return the average score for the first attempt of all tests. The reason I GROUPED BY test_id was so that I could fetch the first attempt. If I were to GROUP BY user would this still work?

Comment: @TommyArnold - You can do this in the outer query and add `AVG`, but in this case, you won't get the results for each min id, you will get only one row with only one average. The problem is, in SQL you can't use an aggregate function without a group by, but in mysql you can do this, and in this case it will take a random value for other columns and you will get only one row as a result, take a look here if you add another average: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c924/5 . I suggest that you remain the original query, and do another query with the extra average.